# MYSQL can REGEXP return in same order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, sql-order-by

I'm using REGEXP to get vehicle names from a database by giving it parameters from another query. The first query is checking what vehicles the user has bought, sorts them by the amount and puts them into an array.

I'm giving id's as parameters to REGEXP like so: '3|5|1|2', and it's returning them sorted in numerical order (vehicle name for 1,2,3,5 instead of vehicle name for 3,5,1,2). I want them returned the same way I entered them or if there's a way to do that in PHP rather than SQL, please share it!

```
EXAMPLE:
$vehicles_user_has = array (         //from the first query
//ID => AMOUNT
"2" => "5"    //id2 = firetruck
"1" => "3"   //id1 = police car
"4" => "1"  //id4 = ambulance
);

$onlyid = implode("|", (array_keys($user_vehicles_array))); ----> gives me "2|1|4"

$findnames = $conn->prepare("SELECT vehicle_name,vehicle_id FROM vehicles WHERE vehicle_id REGEXP '$onlyid'");
$findnames->execute();

while ($row = $findnames->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['vehicle_name'] . " x " . $user_vehicles_array[$row['vehicle_id']] . "<br>";
}

This returns them sorted by ID (1,2,4):
Police car x 3
Firetruck x 5
Ambulance x 1

I want it to return:
Ambulance x 1
Police car x 3
Firetruck x 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could the [`ORDER BY FIELD()` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(vehicle_id, 2, 1, 4)
```

This requires you to enumerate the values that you expect in the function arguments, in the order in which you want them in the resultset.

I would also recommend against using a regex to filter for a list of `id`s: this is not efficient, and not scalable. Instead, you should construct a list for the `IN` operator.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot buddy :)